# what is result code or data returned by give intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I am installing a package using intent.
I can install it alright, but this is what i want to do.

I would call install intent like

```
startActivityForResult(installIntent,requestCode);
```

now i want to check in OnActivityResult, whether the app i wanted to install was actually installed or not? 
So does installer return any result code or extra data indicating this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The resultCode will be
>   `RESULT_CANCELED` if the activity
>   explicitly returned that, didn't
>   return any result, or crashed during
>   its operation.

But you can specify it before finishing the child activity, and initiate it:

```
* RESULT_CANCELED
* RESULT_OK
* RESULT_FIRST_USER
* [...]
```

Before returning from your child activity (before explicitly calling `finish()` or inside the `onDestroy()` method), you can specify your result:

```
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
//optional:
finish();
```

To check the result code, you have to override the `onActivityResult` method of your parent activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode)
    {
        case RESULT_OK:
            [...]
            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            [...]
             break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the procedure. What i mean to ask is, what exactly is returned by installer activity after install or install canceled. I tried RESULT_OK and RESULT_CANCELED. But here everytime it returns RESULT_CANCELED only

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'onActivityResult' in 'Object' (when I tried adding a super)