# How to get a callback when completing the action of setting an alarm?

Tags: java, android

I am developing an application that performs multiple tasks one after the other. One of them is setting an alarm. That is why I have to get a callback when this action is completed. I tried to use onActivityResult but it did not work. Here is my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    setAlarm(new String[] {"0", "42"});
}

private void setAlarm(String[] values) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM);
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, Integer.parseInt(values[0]));
    intent.putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, Integer.parseInt(values[1]));
    startActivityForResult(intent, 42);
}

@Override
public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode) {
    super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
    if (requestCode == 42) {
        Log.i("startActivityForResult", "...");
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.i("onActivityResult", "...");
    if (requestCode == 42) {
        Log.i("onActivityResult", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    }
}
```

The startActivityForResult-method is called, but the onActivityResult-method is not and I do not know why. Can somebody help me.

Answer (score 1):

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TimePicker myTimePicker;
    Button buttonstartSetDialog;
    TextView textAlarmPrompt;
    TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog;

    final static int RQS_1 = 1;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textAlarmPrompt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarmprompt);

        buttonstartSetDialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startAlaram);
        buttonstartSetDialog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                textAlarmPrompt.setText("");
                openTimePickerDialog(false);

            }
        });

    }

    private void openTimePickerDialog(boolean is24r) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(MainActivity.this,
                onTimeSetListener, calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),
                calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE), is24r);
        timePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Alarm Time");

        timePickerDialog.show();

    }

    OnTimeSetListener onTimeSetListener = new OnTimeSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay, int minute) {

            Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
            Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();

            calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hourOfDay);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
            calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

            if (calSet.compareTo(calNow) <= 0) {
                // Today Set time passed, count to tomorrow
                calSet.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
            }

            setAlarm(calSet);
        }
    };

    private void setAlarm(Calendar targetCal) {

        textAlarmPrompt.setText("\n\n***\n" + "Alarm is set "
                + targetCal.getTime() + "\n" + "***\n");

        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(),
                pendingIntent);

    }  
}
```

Reciver.java

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context k1, Intent k2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(k1, "Alarm received!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

}
```

main_activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/startAlaram"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Set Alaram Time" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/alarmprompt"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest.xml

```
<application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
         <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote" />
    </application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it by checking resultCode instead of requestCode:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (resultCode)
    {
        case RESULT_OK:
            [...]
            break;
        case RESULT_CANCELED:
            [...]
             break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

My answear is copied form here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5674322/10802597

Comment: The onActivityResult-method is never called and I need to check the requestCode, too.